# Getting returned type in an Assignment statement

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

How i can get the type of an Assignment Statement using JDT.

I am traversing through a class file using an ASTVisitor, to find the instances of assignment which are having date (Calendar) as the type. Though i am able to find such instances for VaraibleDeclarationStatement using the getType method, the Assignment node doesn't have such method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment is decomposed into the LHS and RHS, so check the type of the RHS expression.

Comment: The node.getLeftHandSide() method will return an Expression. Expression also doesn't have a getType method.

Comment: RHS = RightHandSide. Every expression has a determined type in Java. I would be surprised if there is no way to access that information through the Eclipse AST.

Comment: Checked right now, it's there of course. You need to use the `ITypeBinding` through the `resolveTypeBinding` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I was able to get the type using `node.getRightHandSide().resolveTypeBinding().getTypeDeclaration().getName()`

Comment: Try stepping back and doing `node.resolveTypeBinding()` directly since  `Assignment` is also an expression. The type of the assignment as a whole may be guided by the type of the variable you are assigning to, so it may be broader, and if primitives are involved, there could be a conversion from RHS into the type of the assignment target.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. That was quick and informative. Marking as the best answer.

Comment: I am now using 'node.resolveTypeBinding().getTypeDeclaration().getName()'

Comment: If you tested it for one case and it worked, then this is the proper way to do it.